# Getting a class attribute in a method

Tags: python

I have this class and method:

```
class Person(object):            
    def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = personname
          self.surname = personsurname
    def changenameorsurname(self, x, y):
         self.x = y
         return
AdamSmith = Person ("Adam", "Smith")
```

I want to use method `changenameorsurname` to change `AdamSmith`'s `name` or `surname`, but if I use this code I'm getting a `NameError`"

```
AdamSmith.changenameorsurname(personname, Dave)
```

Result:

```
NameError: name personname is not defined.
```

Is there elegant way to reference `personname` in code like this? Or do I have to make two separate methods like this?

```
def changename(self,  y):
    self.name = y
    return

AdamSmith.changename(Dave)
```

Comment: 1) use 'personname' (put it in a string). 2) look into [setattr](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/setattr), it's what you need. 3) Your __init__ method should fail - where are the `personname` and `personsurname` variables coming from?

Comment: Your code makes little sense. Fix `__init__` before you move on to more complex tasks. You will get a name error long before the change function

Comment: @rassar 's answer is the best, although note that in Python if you're not trying to implement custom setters and getters, you can just write `AdamSmith.name = "Liam"` to set the attribute.

Comment: You're using the wrong terminology. There are no class attributes involved—`name` and `surname` are both _instance_ attributes. Also in the code at the end, `AdamSmith.changename(Dave)` is not a method, it's a _call_ to the method `changename()` of the `Person` class instance named `AdamSmith`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Your init method needs to be fixed so you can properly construct a Person object. You can have your changenameorsurname() method take one argument that is a name and a second argument that determines whether that name is the first name or the surname. Here, I have set the default to first name.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, surname):
          self.first_name = first_name
          self.surname = surname
    def changenameorsurname(self, name, first = True):
        if first:
            self.first_name = name
        else:
            self.surname = name
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.surname}'

some_guy = Person ("Adam", "Smith")
print(some_guy) #Adam Smith

some_guy.changenameorsurname("Michael")
print(some_guy) #Michael Smith

some_guy.changenameorsurname("Jones", first=False)
print(some_guy) #Michael Jones
```